# Updating UI options from reactivePoll in shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I've been searching all day and can't seem to figure this out. I'll try my best to create a similar example to what I'm working with, though it is challenging as things are in an SQL data base.

I have a `shiny` app that is reading data from an SQL data base and I am using `reactivePoll()` inside the server to check the data base every 10 minutes for any new sales data that may have come in. The issue is that `reactivePoll()` is in the `server` and while I can get it to update every 10 min (I can see it happen), it doesn't get new data because the UI is not influenced by the server since the data is pulled from the data base to start with.

Here is an example:

**Simulate Data in PostgreSQL Database**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

start <- as.POSIXct("2010-07-15")
interval <- 120
end <- start + as.difftime(3, units="days")
time_seq <- seq(from=start, to=end, by = 10000)

store <- rep(LETTERS[1:13], each = length(time_seq))
sales_date <- rep(time_seq, times = 13)
sales <- round(runif(n = length(store), min = 10000, max = 30000), 2)

df <- data.frame(store, sales_date, sales)
df %>% head()

  store          sales_date    sales
1     A 2010-07-15 00:00:00 21026.10
2     A 2010-07-15 02:46:40 24478.58
3     A 2010-07-15 05:33:20 21636.65
4     A 2010-07-15 08:20:00 26098.41
5     A 2010-07-15 11:06:40 22325.20
6     A 2010-07-15 13:53:20 15024.09
```

**Query Database to get data for shiny app**

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
conn <- dbConnect(drv,  
                  host = "things",
                  port = 666,
                  user = "username",
                  password = "password",
                  dbname = "prod")

df <- dbGetQuery(conn,
                      "SELECT store
                      sales_date,
                      sales
                      FROM sql_df")
```

**Create user interface using the initial query**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectizeInput(inputId = "store",
                 label = "Choose Stores:",
                 choices = unique(df$store),
                 multiple = T),
  
  sliderInput(inputId = "sales_date",
              label = "Choose Date Range:",
              min = min(df$sales_date),
              max = max(df$sales_date),
              value = c(min(df$sales_date), max(df$sales_date))),
  
  DTOutput(outputId = "sales_tbl")
)
```

**Create the server with reactivePoll() to check for new data**

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  ## check server for new data every 10min
  sqlData <- reactivePoll(intervalMillis = 600000,
                          session,
                          
                          checkFunc = function(){
                            Sys.time()
                          },
                          ## re-pull data every 10min
                          valueFunc = function(){
                            drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
                            conn <- dbConnect(drv,  
                                                    host = "things",
                                                    port = 666,
                                                    user = "username",
                                                    password = "password",
                                                    dbname = "prod")
                            
                            sql_dat <- dbGetQuery(conn,
                                            "SELECT store
                                            sales_date,
                                            sales
                                            FROM sql_df")
                            
                            dbDisconnect(conn)
                            
                            sql_dat
                            
                          }
                            )
  ## get required data from the UI
  dat <- reactive({
    d <- sqlData() %>%
      filter(store %in% input$store,
             sales_date %in% input$sales_date)
    
    d
  })
  ## write data table
  output$sales_tbl <- renderDataTable({
    dat() %>%
      datatable()
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is what I'm asking even possible? Can I some how have the UI be dependent on the reactive data within the Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `updateXX` functions in combination with an `observeEvent` when the `sqlData()` changes:

Include this in your `server`:

```
observeEvent(sqlData(), {
  updateSelectizeInput(session,
                       "store",
                       choices = unique(sqlData()$store))
  
  updateSliderInput(session,
                    "sales_date",
                    min = min(sqlData()$sales_date),
                    max = max(sqlData()$sales_date),
                    value = c(min(sqlData()$sales_date), max(sqlData()$sales_date)))
})
```

Comment: Ah, that worked! Can't believe I forgot about the `updateXX` functions. Thanks. If I were to set it to only pull data in the server if there is new data there, I'm assuming I can do that with an `if` statement within the `function()` portion of the  `checkFunc = function()` code?